# Maven - should I use the jar in dependency tree directly?

Tags: maven, maven-2, dependencies, maven-3

Assume that the existed project dependency tree is:

```
     MyProject:jar:0.1.0
     +- DependencyJar:jar:1.0.3:compile
     |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:14.0:compile
```

And I want to use `guava` from now on.

My question is should I only define `DependencyJar` or both `DependencyJar and guava` in my pom.xml?

What is the best practice?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to declare in your `pom.xml` all dependencies that are directly used by your project.

You should not rely on transitive behavior since `DependencyJar` can later choose to remove `guava` from its dependencies. Thus, an upgrade of `DependencyJar` could lead `MyProject` to not compile.

This best practice is consistent with [maven dependency plugin's analyze-mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) behavior, which can tell you used dependencies which are not declared in your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks. The plugin `analyze-mojo ` is so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest to add direct dependencies to all code you need to compile.

If a future version of your current dependency suddenly doesn't use a transitive dependency anymore, you can have a hard time to find the issue and to fix it.

It also is useful for documentation purposes to know your direct dependencies.

The [Maven Dependency Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) can help you with the analysis.

Answer (score 1):

It is not required as such if it is coming transitively from its parent and you are sure that it will always be there , **but it is highly recommended to mention all the dependencies directly in your pom file on which your project depends**.

As an addon to understand how dependency flows across your project structure , I would like to suggest to read [Maven Dependency Scopes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) , that will give you more clear picture in terms of your question